# Shrink and move /home partition onto another HDD

Tags: partitioning, arch-linux

On arch linux with gpt uefi, installed /home partition on a separate HDD, how can I shrink it and move it back?

Answer (score 0):

1) Copy your home directory to your local drive.

2) Set your home directory to the local path

```
sudo usermod --home /path/to/dir
```

see [`man usermod`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod)

3) As [suggested here](https://superuser.com/a/661338/331766), use [GParted](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GParted) to resize your external drive.

---

I don't have a lot of experience with this, so I just used google. Please consider doing so as well - it is more polite. 
https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: need to cut down the extra space (un-utilized space) on the partition